# VCL TTimer stops when a window dragged or pull down menu clicked

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-2010

I have [`TTimer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TTimer) enabled and is supposed to run non-stop forever until the user stop it. However, it doesn't work that way. Within `OnTimer`event, it processes window messages over and over again in milliseconds.

For instance, here is a snippet of my code.

```
procedure TDXCommDlg.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  if Scanning then
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := false;
    Timer2.Enabled := false;
     while not PostMessage(Handle,WM_USER + 10,1234,5678) do;
     Timer1.Enabled := true;
  end;
end;
```

What happens is this. While the TTimer is enabled and running, you drag any windows of the application or click on pull down menu the TTimer event completely stops working, even though I have taken precautionary steps in other part of the code to prevent this from happening. However, it doesn't seem to be helping.

The only way to restart the `OnTimer` event is to stop and restart the Timer by the user through TButton event.

The same code or program works fine under Windows XP compiled with Delphi 7. Currently, I am using Windows 7 and Delphi 2010 to rebuild my system.

I will try to give you more information. What I am working on is a copyrighted software.

There is a user defined procedure called HandleMsg. It actually processes the serial port messages. HandleMsg is set to the Application event onMessage;

Application.onMessage:=HandleMsg();

PostMessage is associated with onMessage event of the application.

Whenever PostMessage is called, it fires onMessage event which is set to HandleMsg().

Here more of my code:

```
 procedure TDXCommDlg.HandleMsg(var
 Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
 begin
      Handled := false;
      case Msg.message of
      WM_USER + 10:
              begin
                   if (Msg.wParam = 1111) and (Msg.lParam = 2222) then
                   begin
                     SendLanMessage;
                     Handled := true;
                   end
                   else if (Msg.wParam = 1234) and (Msg.lParam = 5678) then
                   begin
                        SendMessage;
                        Handled := true;
                   end
                   else
                   begin
                     if (Msg.wParam = 4321) then
                     begin
                       MainFrm.CloseWindow(TViewFrm(Msg.lParam).WinCap);
                     end;
                   end;
              end;
      end; { case } end;
```

HandleMsg() responds to PostMessage. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What's this code supposed to do? `while not PostMessage(Handle,WM_USER + 10,1234,5678) do;` Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I added a timer, label and menu to a form. I implemented a timer event handler that incremented a counter and displayed it in the label. The label kept on changing when my menu was dropped down, and when the form drags. I've no idea what your problem is. You need to make it clearer but adding enough code for us to be able to understand and reproduce your issue.

Comment: This code processes serial communication over and over in milliseconds. It communicates with an external hardware through DB9 serial port. The serial messages are processed as they are sent out as a window messages. So, the application itself doesn't need to directly process them and overload other part of the application or worse slow it down.

Comment: David, I did do that like you did in my application, but it hung up after progressively running slower and slower. What I wrote originally works flawlessly but fails once you dragged its window or clicked on its pull-down menu.

Comment: @user since it works as expected when I try to replicate what you say you are doing, I feel you need to supply more details. You don't have to do that, but it might help you get an answer!

Comment: That PostMessage loop is a really bad idea. If PostMessage fails, what rational reason do you have to expect that immediately trying it again would succeed? If it fails, do as the documentation tells you and call GetLastError to find out what's wrong. (But if the problem you're reporting occurs even when that line is absent, then remove it from the question since it's irrelevant.)

Comment: Cannot duplicate either. But note *"The WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message. The GetMessage and PeekMessage functions post this message only when no other higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue."* from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `while not PostMessage(...) do;` does it ever fail?

Comment: `PostMessage` does not trigger `OnMessage`. It simply places a message on the message queue of the thread associated `Handle`. This message will then get processed when the queue is pumped. The point is that it is *asynchronous*.  Irrespective of copyright, can you post a complete program that exhibits your fault, because we're all having trouble getting a handle on the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases (starting to size/move window or opening a menu) the last message dispatched from `TApplication.ProcessMessage` is `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` (or a `WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN` if caption and system menu exists and clicked on the caption.. or a `WM_RBUTTONUP` if opening a context menu, etc..). Common to all is they are starting a modal message loop.

For instance the below is from `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` documentation:

> The WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE message is sent
>   one time to a window after it enters
>   the moving or sizing modal loop.
>   [....] The operation is complete when
>   DefWindowProc returns.

After a modal message loop is started the `HandleMessage` call in `TApplication.Run` will not return until `DefWindowProc` for the relevant window returns (in the `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` case for instance, the dispatched message will cause a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` to be sent to the window which will start the modal message loop and will not return until moving/sizing is complete). So you won't be able to use an `OnMessage` handler of the application in this period which is called in `TApplication.ProcessMessage`.

Your solution is simple. Instead of using the `OnMessage` handler, handle the message with a message handler of your form:

```
const
  WMUSER_10 = WM_USER + 10;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure WmUser10(var Msg: TMsg); message WMUSER_10;
  public
  end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WMUSER_10, 1234, 5678);
end;

procedure TForm1.WmUser10(var Msg: TMsg);
begin
  //
end;
```

Or, put your code in the `OnTimer` event, since `WM_TIMER` is itself *posted*.

Comment: Works great. I did realize I could have put the code in onTimer, but I guess I am lazy. Now only I have see how long it runs before my software craps out.

Comment: Glad your issue is resolved (for now ;)). Not that it effects the resolution, but I edited a bit the answer with an attempt to clarify what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. The Windows timer is based on a message queue flag, and it is the lowest priority event. When you start resizing a window, the timer flag in the main application event queue stops being processed, and the timer will stop. Nothing you can do about that. To be clear, ordinary messages will still work, but the timer stops. This is very easy to test.

Now, to resolve this, you can either send yourself WM_USER messages, which should get through, or the better solution is to use a thread to do the critical operation and use the timer to update UI from information that the thread updates. Then when the user resizes the window, you get a UI pause, but the operations are continuing.

Comment: Okay. But it still is not clear for me . i need a practical example

Comment: -1 Not true. Message queue gets pumped whilst resizing. It also gets pumped with menus dropped down and when moving the window.

Comment: This isn't true -- the Message queue continues to be processed when a window is resized -- hence all the WM_SIZE messages.

Comment: This can actually happen if the resize triggers high priority messages, such as complex custom paint events that don't complete before the next mouse-originated event is fired. The source of the issue is then however not the resize itself, but what it triggers, and how it can saturate the message queue.

Comment: Hmm, I've clarified that it is the Timer flag that isn't being processed, and that ordinary messages are still viable. This was implied in my first solution, but not explicit.

Comment: WM_TIMER gets pumped for me, so long as queue is not saturated.

Comment: I wonder if they fixed this in Windows 7 or Vista then? It is certainly the case in XP that the timer stalls.